# Solidity: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition. function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-debugging, ganache

I am using Truffle together with Ganache and I can't get this code to run:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21<0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract UniqueAsset is ERC721{

using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
mapping(string => uint8) hashes;

  constructor() public ERC721("UniqueAsset", "UNA") {}
}

function awardItem(address recipient, string memory hash, string memory metadata)
  public
  returns (uint256)
  
{  
    require(hashes[hash] != 1);

    hashes[hash] = 1;
  
    _tokenIds.increment();
  
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
  
    _mint(recipient, newItemId);
  
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, metadata);
  
    return newItemId;
  
}
```

it shows me the following error:

```
:15:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
function awardItem(address recipient, string memory hash, string memory metadata)
^------^
```

Anybody an idea whats wrong?

Comment: Remove the bracket line 13 after the constructor and add it at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you need to change:

- Your pragma statement needs a space in it between the versions. Change it to `pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;`
- The OpenZeppelin contracts you are importing require Solidity 0.8.0 or greater. You will need to change your pragma statement to reflect this
- You have a closing bracket on line 13 after the constructor. That should not be there -- move it to the end of the file.
- `_setTokenURI()` is not a function on the contract you are importing. See more [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/function-settokenuri-in-erc721-is-gone-with-pragma-0-8-0/5978).

Comment: Hi Shane, thank you for your answer

unfortunately I'm not a full stack developer yet, so i don't understand a lot from the link you've sent  :-| 
can you help me with which function should i use instead?

thank again

Comment: I am not sure. I think it would be a good exercise to figure that out, as the learnings you will gain by figuring that out should help design the rest of the contract!